# DRF - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "matchteam-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but I tried most of the answers and none worked so far...

The error I get is:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /matches/1/

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "matchteam-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

However, matchteam-detail is in my urlpatterns:

```
<URLPattern '^matchteams/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='matchteam-detail']>, <URLPattern '^matchteams/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='matchteam-detail']>,
```

This error happens on a many-to-many relationships with a "through" model on Django REST Framework, when accessing a "Match" object on the API:

**models.py**

```
class MatchTeam(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey("teams.Team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    match = models.ForeignKey("matches.Match", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Match(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField("teams.Team", through='matches.MatchTeam')

class Team(models.Model):
    matches = models.ManyToManyField("matches.Match", through='matches.MatchTeam')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MatchTeamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MatchTeam
        fields = ['id', 'team', 'match', 'score']


class MatchSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    teams = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        view_name='matchteam-detail',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ['id', 'teams']

class TeamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'teams', TeamViewSet)
router.register(r'matches', MatchViewSet)
router.register(r'matchteams', MatchTeamViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The views are defined with ModelViewSets.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a third  parameter to `router.register` which then gives you the `matchteam-detail`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'teams', TeamViewSet, 'teams')
router.register(r'matches', MatchViewSet, 'matches')
router.register(r'matchteams', MatchTeamViewSet, 'matchteams')
```

I don't know why you need this now, but you do.  It got me on my django 1 -> 2 migration.  Kicked me in the teeth too.

Comment: Added that code and got the same error, and now "matchteam-detail" does not show up in the urlpatterns:
    <URLPattern '^matchteams/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='matchteams-detail']>, <URLPattern '^matchteams/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='matchteams-detail']>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but removing:

```
teams = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    read_only=True,
    view_name='matchteam-detail',
)
```

from the serializers.py works!